# Extracting patterns with awk within a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have this tab delimited file.

Test.txt

```
chr1      10111412      apples
chr2      195121230     pears
chr2      991924122     elephants
```

If I want stuff in column 1 from chr2,

`awk '/chr2\t/ Test.txt`

Output:

```
chr2      195121230     pears
chr2      991924122     elephants
```

But if I have a couple hundred million lines from chr1 to chr25, and need to split them up into chr-specific text files, I thought of doing this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for num in $(seq 1 25)
do
awk '/chr$num\t/' Test.txt > chr$num.txt
done
```

I also tried changing the awk to sed

`sed -n 'chr$num\t/p' Test.txt`

Both of course failed spectacularly. I suspect the script recognises `'/chr$num\t/'` as a single variable. How can I break this recognition pattern and get the script to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done much simpler with `awk`:

```
awk '{print >> $1".txt"}' input.file
```

That's it.

---

If the file is pretty large and you have a high number of different values of the first column you may run out of file descriptors. In that case you need to close the file after writing to it:

```
awk '{f=$1".txt"; print >> f; close(f)}' input.file
```

Answer (score 5):

You can adapt this code:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^chr[0-9]+$/ { x = $1; gsub(/chr/, "file.", x); print > x }'
```

Given input stream:

```
chr1 d e
chr1 f g
chr44 abc def
chr3 cba fed
```

It generates 3 files, `file.1`, `file.3` and `file.44`.  You can control the file name generated easily enough by messing with the `gsub()` function call.

Note that this makes a single pass through the data file, which is a lot more sensible than making 25 passes through a massive file.

Tested with both GNU and Mac OS X (BSD) versions of `awk`.

Comment: This is far too complicated. Use `awk` super-power!

Comment: No response?! This does a) not answer the question correctly (wrong output file name) b) does not use awk's goodies like `-F` c) crash on too many open file descriptors. Wonder why this got 3 times upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Sorry for being that harsh, but that's the basic column juggling supported by awk and simplicity is a must to have here, since that's one of the basic features of awk. Having 3 ups, you see, there is still a need to teach that.

Comment: Neither my answer nor your answer needs to use `-F` (that's overkill; `awk` splits on tabs by default).  My answer shows how you can change the name based on just the numeric part.  You're right that it isn't necessary if the file name simply needs to be `chr1.txt` or whatever.  Your point about too many file descriptors is valid, as is your fix; I didn't test on big enough data sets.

Comment: Good point! `-F'\t'` isn't required! I knew you are a smart guy! My second solution isn't perfect. A perfect awk script would truncate the output file on it's first usage to make sure that the command is re-entrent.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `"` instead of a `'`.

*Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will (for example variables, backticks, certain \ escapes, etc...).*

Try the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for num in $(seq 1 25)
do
awk "/chr$num\t/" Test.txt > chr$num.txt
done
```

Comment: Ah. Silly me. Sorry, what is the difference?

Comment: In general, you do better to relay shell variables to awk with `awk -v var="$value" … '…awk script…' file*` (where the `-v` sets an `awk` variable `var` to the value in `$value` (a shell variable).  You can have multiple `-v` options for a single `awk` script.